# How to store name of class in a variable in Java

Tags: java

For example, I have three classes:

```
public class A{public static void doSth(){}}
public class B{public static void doSth(){}}
public class C{public static void doSth(){}}
```

Then I have a variable:

```
private int controlVariable;
```

Then based on the value of this controlVariable, I want to invoke the doSth() method in different class above. For example:

```
switch (i)
{
case 1:
A.doSth();
break;
case 2:
B.doSth();
break;
case 3:
C.doSth();
break;
}
```

However, using the above approach is very tedious. Can I use a variable to store the name of class. For example:

```
classNameVariable = A; 
classNameVaribale.doSth();
```

Can anyone help me with this? Please do not use inheritance.

Comment: There are no interfaces for static methods.

Comment: Your question smells to me of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: This is going to be very painful unless you explain why the methods need to be static specifically.

Comment: why is inheritance not an option?

Comment: @fateddy Because I do not want to create an object. That's why I define the method as a static one.

Comment: Why do you want to work without objects? Having a common super interface and non-static methods would be the usual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you could use method references:

```
public class A {
    public static void doSth() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void doSth() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void doSth() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable[] methods = { A::doSth, B::doSth, C::doSth };

        int controlVariable = 2;

        methods[controlVariable].run(); // C
    }
}
```

In this example, `controlVariable` is a `0`-based index.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `A.getClass().getSimpleName()` will return a string with the class name as given in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get class from class name:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("your class package"); 
Method method = cls.getMethod("methodName", arguments);
Object o = method.invoke(null, "whatever");
```

Hope this will help you.